# Как найти кнопку по дата атрибуту и добавить к ней класс в .each()

Tags: javascript, jquery, each

Всем привет!

Мучаюсь второй час, не могу никак повесить класс на кнопку. Делаю календарь с вебинарами и за 10 минут до начала надо добавлять класс к кнопке, который сделает ее активной и начнет пропускать на стрим. Расписание проверяется каждую минуту и по наступлении значения в 10 мин до начала надо вешать класс.

```
setInterval(function (){
    let ids = []

    $('.live-event').each(function(){
        ids.push($(this).attr('data-id'));
    })

    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "/app/php/ajax.php",
        data: {
            action: "handle_events_buttons",
            eventId: ids
        },
        success(data) {
            
            $.each(data.buttons_info, function(button) {
                $('.live-event button[data-id='+button.event_id+']').removeClass('btn-danger').addClass(button.status)
            })

            //console.log(data)
            //{type: true, event_id: "17", status: "btn-danger", start: -47, finish: 732}
            //ответ есть осталось повесить класс btn-danger

        }
    })
},60000)
```

Кнопка находится внутри `foreach` поэтому у каждой кнопки есть `data-id="event_id"`

```
<button data-id="'.$event["post_id"].'" class="btn btn-secondary live-event">Прямой эфир</button>
```

Для примера в расписании 2 мероприятия, одно с неактианой кнопкой т.к оно не началось второе уже активно и надо на кнопку этого ивента повесить класс

```
//ответ echo json_encode(['buttons_info' => $updated_buttons]);

buttons_info: Array(2)
0: {type: true, event_id: "12", status: "", start: 1440, finish: 1500}
1: {type: true, event_id: "17", status: "btn-danger", start: -59, finish: 720}
```

Comment: а проблема в чём сейчас? ну код вроде правильный

Comment: Класс не вешается, в этом и проблема.(( Ошибок в консоли нет, ответ приходит верный без ошибок.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На сколько я вижу `.live-event` и `button` это один и тот же элемент, а значит запись  `.live-event button[data-id...` не рабочая, т.к. ищет `button` в элементе с классом `.live-event`. Скорее всего надо только

```
$('[data-id='+button.event_id+']')....
```

либо

```
$('.live-event[data-id='+button.event_id+']')....
```

либо

```
$('button.live-event[data-id='+button.event_id+']')....
```

---

Еще у функции [jQuery.each](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) в колбэк первым аргументов прилетает индекс элемента, а вторым - значение, поэтому нужно писать `$.each(data, function(index, button)`, а не `$.each(data, function(button)`

```js
let data = [
    {type: true, event_id: "12", status: "btn-success", start: 1440, finish: 1500},
    {type: true, event_id: "17", status: "btn-danger", start: -59, finish: 720}
];

$.each(data, function(index, button) {
    console.log(button.status);
    $('button.live-event[data-id='+button.event_id+']').removeClass('btn-danger').addClass(button.status);
})
```

```css
.btn-danger {
    background: red;
}

.btn-success {
    background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button data-id="12" class="btn btn-secondary live-event">Прямой эфир</button>
<button data-id="17" class="btn btn-secondary live-event">Прямой эфир</button>
```

Comment: Я пробовал и так и так, все равно ничего.

Comment: Короче вот так заработало $.each(data.buttons_info, function(i,button) осталось понять что значит i))

Comment: @Alex.H первым параметром передаётся индекс, а вторым значение, как раз добавил в ответ

Comment: да-да точно, круто.